# Chrome Sockets TCP is sending data but not receiving data

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, sockets, ionic-framework

I'm using the Chrome Sockets TCP plugin for Cordova in my Ionic app. I can easily send data to my server, but I cannot receive anything, no matter what I do, the onReceive event just won't fire. The send() method works just fine, but the onReceive doesn't even run, which I know because I can't see anything in the console. I've looked at so many examples but no example helps. What could be my problem? My code is below. (the line that says this.str2ab(req) is a function call that changes my string called req to an arrayBuffer)

```
//Connects to the server
connect() {
  (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, (createInfo) => {
     this.id = createInfo.socketId;

     (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(this.id, this.ip, this.port, (result) => {
        console.log("Connected to the server " + result);
    });
  });
};


//Function for sending and receiving data
getStatus() {

  // Send data
  (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.send(this.id, this.str2ab(this.req),
    (resultCode) => {
        console.log("Data sent to new TCP client connection.")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resultCode))
    });

  // Start receiving data
  (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(() => {
    console.log("This is the received object")
    console.log("Data received")
 });

 (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.setPaused(this.id, false);
};
```

Comment: I didn't use Chrome Sockets TCP plugin, I do use socket.io and I believe it is much easier.  Anyway, by looking at your codes, you created a socket and stored the socket id in this.id, and you use this.id to send message to your socket server.  However, the codes for receive does not contain any 'this.id', did you miss something?  I mean if you create 2 connections to the same server, e.g. this.id1 and this.id2, if you do not include any one of them in the listening event, how can the system knows which connection you want to listen?

Comment: I've been trying to use the id, but still the onReceive wouldn't run. I even tried changing the positioning of the onReceive, putting it inside the connect() function, but it still will not run. Do you have an example of where I would place the id?

Comment: why do you choose Chrome Sockets tcp for Cordova project?  does ios support Chrome socket?  try socket.io, it is so easy to learn and you can run your cordova app or web in any platform including linux browser